# Propagation of touch events

Tags: android, touch, event-propagation

I've got some `ListView`. Each list element is constructed using layout looking like this:

```
<SomeRootLayout android:background="@layout/some_other_selector">
    <TextView android:background="@layout/some_selector"/>
    <TextView android:background="@layout/some_selector"/>
    <ImageView/>
</SomeRootLayout>
```

The `some_selector.xml` is looking like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_stop_pressed" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_stop_default" />
</selector>
```

Now, when the user press the entire row, the each TextView is being pressed as well (not really pressed - no onClick events are generated, however TextViews change its background according to their selectors). Any ideas to tell system NOT to propagate touch events from parent to child views?

Comment: try to create custom ListView, override dispatchTouchEvent and invoke super method there but return true to prevent propagating.

Comment: I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741908/android-child-elements-sharing-pressed-state-with-their-parent-even-when-duplica/7235953#7235953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `android:duplicateParentState="false"` on your textview

Comment: Whether a view has pressed state does not depend on duplicateParentState.