# Android: Child elements sharing pressed state with their parent even when duplicateParentState specified

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a SlidingDrawer element which contains a RelativeLayout element which contains some Button child elements:

```
<SlidingDrawer>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      <Button android:background="@drawable/foo.xml" android:duplicateParentState="false">
      <Button android:background="@drawable/bar.xml" android:duplicateParentState="false">
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

foo.xml and bar.xml have selectors which apply different images depending on the state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/foo_selected" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/foo_selected" />
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/foo_disabled" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/foo_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

The problem I am seeing is that when I click on the sliding drawer handle, the pressed state gets triggered for the buttons and they look pressed too, even though I've specified `duplicateParentState` to false.

Comment: There is a better solution to this problem by subclassing viewgroup and overriding dispatchSetPressed. I have posted the solution on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268890/795245

Comment: I think my question can anwser your qustion.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179431/android-child-view-sharing-pressed-state-from-its-parent-view-in-jelly-bean

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Override the `LinearLayout` class with a subclass. In that subclass override the `setPressed` method and do nothing like so:

```
public class UnpressableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout
{
    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed)
    {
        // Do nothing here. Specifically, do not propagate this message along
        // to our children so they do not incorrectly display a pressed state
        // just because one of their ancestors got pressed.
    }
}
```

Replace `LinearLayout` with an instance of `UnpressableLinearLayout`.

Comment: To avoid of writing new custom layout for any other views (`RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`…), have a look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13813751/1521536), it's simpler.

Answer (score 12):

There is no need to set duplicateParentState to false. This would happen if you make the parent clickable somehow. By default, the pressed state is propagated to the children. Make sure your LinearLayout and RelativeLayout are not clickable.

Comment: Hi Romain Guy, could you document this somewhere? I got this problem yesterday and I solved this by peeking on the source code of ViewGroup. It seems that some states propagate to children and some do not.

Comment: Does this also happens on ICS? I'm having different behaviour on it. Click is not being propagated.

Answer (score 0):

Got same situation with SeekBar.

setting for SeekBar:

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

worked for me