# Pressing ChildView behaves as if ParentView is clicked

Tags: android, view, parent

I found a weird behavior on Android.
Let's say I have a list View and each row is a Linear layout containing a textView.
I set a longClickListener on the listView. Also, I set an onTouchEvent on the textView.
The behavior I want is that if the user press the textView in the list, onTouchEvent should be run. If the user Long-presses outside the textView, it should perform what's defined in the longClickListener.
However, in Android 4.2.1, this behavoir doesn't seem to work.
I found that Google changed the code so that ChildView shares pressed state from its parent view in Jelly Bean. Is this right?
If this is the case, how can I implement the way I want?

On other words, I want the childView and parentView behave independently!!

Any answer would be appreciated!

Below is my CustomTextView.java

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setPressed(false);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPressed(false);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setPressed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Intent.... something
        Start a new activity... pretty straightforward

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Below is the textview of my list_item.xml

```
<com.keek.widget.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail_overlay"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_11"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textColorLink="@color/linkify_blue" />
```

My list is pretty straightforward. It is a plain listView with onLongClickListener which opens a dialog box.

The this is that when I press the textView, both the dialogbox and new activity open at the same time. What I want is that when I press textView, it should open a new activity only not a dialog.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: posted... it's pretty straightward

Comment: I was kind of asking a general question. Did Google really changed the  way child View behaves depending on Parent View? I found a similar issue but couldn't find a workaround..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179431/android-child-view-sharing-pressed-state-from-its-parent-view-in-jelly-bean